# a:link, a:visted, a:hover, and a:active not working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I've used a:hover before; I don't know why it isn't working now. Here's the code.

```
<style>

    body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #F0F0EE;
    }

    p {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #2B2B2B;
    font-size: 13px;

    a:link {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #557777;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

    a:visited {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #557777;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #3F7F77;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

    a:active {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #557777;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

</style>
```

The links appear like the default links for some reason. (They are purple because I have already visited them and they are underlined.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your `p {}` selector with the last `}`

```
p {
font-family: Arial;
color: #2B2B2B;
font-size: 13px;
```

**}  <---------**

```
a:link {
```

Comment: LOL SORRY NOOB MISTAKE THERE